# Line 58:26: 'KTUtil' is not defined

Tags: reactjs, import

when i try to import js files
import  * as Sb from'./assets/js/scripts.bundle.js';

import * as Wb from'./assets/js/widgets.bundle.js';

import * as Wi from'./assets/js/custom/widgets.js';

import * as NT from'./assets/js/custom/utilities/modals/new-target.js';

dom shows me this :
'KTUtil' is not defined
'moment' is not defined

i try to import js files into react app. then this happenend. ?